# Pyinstaller matlab-engine problem running the .exe on a different machine

Tags: python, matlab, pyinstaller, matlab-engine

I'm working on an application that uses the matlab engine API for python.
The app works fine, without any issue, therefore I wanted to pack it into a single exe.

At first I had an issue given by mlarray, that I solved by compiling with:

```
pyinstaller --additional-hook-dir=hooks --onefile main.py
```

Now on my own computer the .exe file works fine, but as soon as I try to run it on a different machine (with Matlab installed), it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matlab\engine\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlabengineforpython3_8'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matlab\engine\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
  File "os.py", line 1109, in add_dll_directory
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:\\Matlab\\extern\\engines\\python\\..\\..\\..\\bin\\win64'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "matlab\engine\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
OSError: Please reinstall MATLAB Engine for Python or contact MathWorks Technical Support for assistance: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:\\Matlab\\extern\\engines\\python\\..\\..\\..\\bin\\win64'
[10656] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

It seems that it can't find the module "matlabengineforpython3_8", which in theory is in the engine folder in the matlab installation path.
Then it's looking for a file in the wrong place, because the machine doesn't have an F: disk, but my computer does.

Comment: Hey were you able to work a way around it?

Comment: @Elan nope, just removed Matlab from the project, I used Matplotlib instead.